# How does numpy convert dtypes when using np.add(), np.subtract(), etc.?

Tags: python, numpy

Broadcasted math functions in numpy like [np.add()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.add.html) or [np.subtract()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.subtract.html) allow you to pass a `dtype` parameter. Let's say I have two arrays of type `np.uint8`. If I add or subtract them normally, I might end up with overflow. So, I can pass them to a function and specify the `dtype` like

```py
x = np.random.randint(low=0, high=256, size=(10, 10), dtype=np.uint8)
y = np.random.randint(low=0, high=256, size=(10, 10), dtype=np.uint8)
my_sum = np.add(x, y, dtype=np.int16)
```

and I get the correct result as the sum.

I want to know how numpy handles this dtype conversion. Are `x` and `y` first casted into `np.int16`, and then added? Or is numpy able to add them without casting and store the result as a different dtype?

The interest is if I have a very large array I don't want to cast the arrays before adding, subtracting, or using other broadcastable functions. I want to maintain the original arrays as `np.uint8` and yet produce a `np.int16` output.

I have tried searching for the source code for these functions, but cannot find it anywhere.

**EDIT**

Here's what it says about the `dtype` parameter in the [ufunc documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) (thanks @hpaulj):

> The dtype keyword allows you to manage a very common problem that arises when naively using ufunc.reduce. Sometimes you may have an array of a certain data type and wish to add up all of its elements, but the result does not fit into the data type of the array. This commonly happens if you have an array of single-byte integers. The dtype keyword allows you to alter the data type over which the reduction takes place (and therefore the type of the output). Thus, you can ensure that the output is a data type with precision large enough to handle your output.

This still does not explicitly explain how `dtype` is altered/overridden, but at least it seems to be the intended usage.

Comment: What you suggest would imply that numpy has to implement every possible combination of inputs-output types. int8+int8 -> int16, int8+int8->int32, int8+int8->int64, int8+int16 -> int16, int8+int16->int32, int8+int16->int64, int16+int16->int32,... and this is just some of the combinations using only a couple of `intX` types, you have to add all possible combinations with floats etc... so obviously it's an implementator nightmare. My guess is that `np.add(,dtype=X)` simply casts x and y to X and does the addition. In this way you only need same-type implementations.

Comment: Can't tell from sure from the source right now, but I'd guess what NumPy does is it creates an output array with the specified dtype, then each pair of values is casted in the addition loop (as opposed to making new whole casted copies of the arrays).

Comment: Are you worried about memory use, speed, or overflow?  Why is important that it does the math with `uint8` values?

Comment: Documentation on `ufunc` casting rules: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/ufuncs.html#casting-rules

Comment: @hpaulj For this question, I'm curious about the memory use. For small arrays it doesn't matter to cast ```np.int8``` to ```np.int16```, but it would be nice to know for very large arrays. And thank you for the link, but what it says about ```dtype``` is pretty ambiguous: "Overrides the dtype of the calculation and output arrays. Similar to signature."